# A bounded buffer producer-consumer code using semaphore

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads, semaphore, producer-consumer

The entire implementation of the critical section using semaphore is what i tried to implement.
The entire code using semaphores is shown:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int buf[256];
int in = 0;
int out = 0;
sem_t full;
sem_t empty;
sem_t mutex;
int buf_size;
int counter = 0;

void *producer(void *arg)
{
    int i, item, *index;
    index = (int *)arg;
    for (i = 0;; i++)
    {
        item = 1000 + i;
        sem_wait(&empty);
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        buf[in] = item;
        in = (in + 1) % (*index);
        counter++;
        printf("\n%d [P%d] ", item, *index);
        sem_post(&mutex);
        sem_post(&full);
        /* if (i % 5 == 0)
            sleep(1); */
    }
}

void *consumer(void *arg)
{
    int i, item, *index;
    index = (int *)arg;
    for (i = 0;;i++)
    {
        sem_wait(&full);
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        item = buf[out];
        out = (out + 1) % (*index);
        counter--;
        printf("\n%d [C%d] ", item, *index);
        sem_post(&mutex);
        sem_post(&empty);
        /* if (i % 5 == 0)
            sleep(1); */
    }
}

int main()
{
    int produce, consume;
    int i;
    printf("\nThe Buffer Size:");
    scanf("%d", &buf_size);
    printf("\nThe Producer:");
    scanf("%d", &produce);
    printf("\nThe Consumer:");
    scanf("%d", &consume);
    pthread_t prod, cons;
    void* exit_status;
    sem_init(&full, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&empty, 0, buf_size);
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
    for (i = 0; i < produce; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&prod, NULL, producer, &i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < consume; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&cons, NULL, consumer, &i);
    }
    pthread_join(prod, &exit_status);
    pthread_join(cons, &exit_status);
    // pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles without error but the output is nothing but the inputs that it takes and then thit just shows 1000 and p1 1001 p2 and values like that

Comment: Few suggestions: 1. Tell what the program is supposed to do. 2. Fix the code formatting, it looks really bad (and, stop using the horrible TABs). 3. Cut away as many lines as possible to only show the essentials.

Answer (score 1):

You create your first producer and then immediately wait for it to terminate with join(), so blocking your main thread.  That producer runs in its for loop, pushing the queue until the 'empty' semaphore has no more units and the producer then blocks.

The main and one producer thread are now both stuck.  The other producers, and all the consumers, are never started.  No consumers means nothing to pop from the queue, so the whole lot is deadlocked.

This is not untypical when using join().